# Is there a way to crack/recover password for MDE file?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a mde file which i had created long back and need to do some changes. Now i don't have the source code or back up of mdb file. Is there a way to get the mdb file. I googled but most of the links are for excel. Can any expert guide me on this issue

Comment: An mde is compiled. There is no way back.

Comment: @Remou Apparently there is, although probably not easily: http://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion_faqs.htm

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only service that can recover an MDE/ACCDe is provided by the guys at [EverythingAccess](http://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion.htm).

I do not know about the quality/cost of that service, but the implementation of [some of their other products](http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.htm) show an intimate knowledge of MS Access internals that I have never seen elsewhere.
Pure wizardry.